# Display a polynomial in exponential generating function form

Tags: output-formatting, latex

Is there an easy way to have Mathematica display a polynomial in "exponential generating function" form?  So, for example, rather than seeing
$$1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + 4 x^3$$
I would like to see
$$1 + \frac{1}{1!} 2 x + \frac{1}{2!} 6 x^2 + \frac{1}{3!} 24 x^3$$
It would be especially nice if the output could also be captured in TeX format, as in TeXForm[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this by a simple replacement rule with the command **Inactive**:

```
(1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + 4 x^3) /.  x_^n_ :> x^n Factorial[n]/Inactive[Factorial][n]
```

which yields the desired output

> 1+2 x+(6 x^2)/(2!)+(24 x^3)/(3!)

In addition, you can directly hit **TeXForm** without any problem and capture the desired form:

```
(1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + 4 x^3) /. x_^n_ :> x^n Factorial[n]/Inactive[Factorial][n] // TeXForm
```

> $\frac{24 x^3}{3!}+\frac{6 x^2}{2!}+2 x+1$

Comment: I understood this as wanting the taylor series. For example, `Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}]` for example, `Sum[term[Exp[x],x,0,n],{n,0,10}]` will give ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3pOwy.png) but may be my understanding was wrong.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the question was about display. Well, s/he now has both answers :D

Comment: By way of clarification, there are many sources of generating functions other than Series[], so I did not intend my question to be limited to the output of Series[].  However, Carl Wolf's example shows that an arbitrary polynomial can be an input to Series[], which then spits it out unaltered, so limiting the action to the output of Series[] is not an actual limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that produces the appearance you requested. First, I define a wrapper that renders coefficients the way you want:

```
MakeBoxes[form[n_,r_], form_] ^:= TagBox[
    RowBox[{MakeBoxes[1/n!], MakeBoxes[r,form]}],
    #&,
    SyntaxForm->Power
]
MakeBoxes[form[0,r_], form_] := MakeBoxes[r, form]
```

For example:

```
form[2,6] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{2!}6$

Then, I define a function to transform a [`SeriesData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData) object (produced by the [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) function):

```
toEGF[HoldPattern@SeriesData[a_,b_,c_,d_,e_,f_]] := Module[
    {orders, coeffs},

    orders = Range[d,d+Length[c]-1];
    coeffs = Replace[
        Transpose[{orders, orders! c}],
        {n_,r_}:>form[n,r]
        {1}
    ];
    SeriesData[a,b,foo,d,e,f]
]
```

Your example:

```
ser = Series[1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3, {x, 0, 3}];
ser //toEGF //TeXForm
```

> $$1+\frac{1}{1!}2 x+\frac{1}{2!}6 x^2+\frac{1}{3!}24 x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$

Comment: Considering the skills you demonstrate here you might have an answer or hint for my question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214361/how-to-make-a-custom-notation-for-factorialpower?noredirect=1#comment548623_214361