# How to improve this custom notation?

Tags: custom-notation

I implemented this custom notation...

```
In[57]:= Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"x_", "↓", "y_"}]] ⟺ 
  ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{" ", 
RowBox[{"FunctionExpand", "[", 
RowBox[{"FactorialPower", "[", 
RowBox[{"x_", ",", "y_"}], "]"}], "]"}]}]]]
```

and works as expected:

```
In[71]:= x↓2

Out[71]= (-1 + x) x
```

What I really want is that when I enter x ^ ( 2 ) that this is interpreted as FactorialPower[x,2] meaning that the outer ( and ) make it a FactorialPower instead of a normal power.

Which changes should I implement to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure if it is what you are asking, but ctrl-6 on my mac gives a shortcut to raise something to a power.  I have to use the arrow keys to move from that to the "normal" line of the equation.  The "6" is the up carrot so if you are using a PC, there is probably an equivalent using the key with the up carrot.

Comment: I have windows, I can do that too with ctr-6. If I create 5^(2) I get 25 instead of 20.

Comment: @niloderoock I don’t understand what you’re looking for. It isn’t clear what you’re trying to shortcut to what. Can you provide a little more context, maybe what the definition of this shortcut should be?

Comment: Falling should give 5*4*3=60 rising should give 5*6*7=210

Comment: Mma has the function FactorialPower which handles this. I am mainly concerned about the formatting / notation. - I am now investigating the Notation Package but that is not an easy package.

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion, the `Notation` package.

Comment: @wuyudi - An edit is nice but an answer is required...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another non-Notation option is to use [`InputAliases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAliases):

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases, "fp"}] = TemplateBox[
    {"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"},
    "FactorialPower",
    SyntaxForm->SuperscriptBox
]
```

Then, typing <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> will generate the desired input.

Comment: So Notation is not necessary after all.

Comment: At the end of the day I want to be able to switch between normal exponents, falling exponents and rising exponents. To start with, I would like ( in "a falling exponents mode" ), x^2-x to display as x^(2). - Could this be the reason why initially Notation was suggested? I hoped the Notation[ _ <=> _] would be able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This code interprets the superscript (achieved with ctrl+6) as `FactorialPower`:

```
MakeExpression[SuperscriptBox[x_, RowBox[{"(", y_, ")"}]], StandardForm] := 
  MakeExpression[RowBox[{FactorialPower, "[", x, ",", y, "]"}], StandardForm]
```

Then an input of

$a^{(b+c)}$

leads to

```
FactorialPower[a,b+c]
```

Comment: How can I add FunctionExpand after FactorialPower ? I want (x+5)^(3) to evaluate to (x+5)(x+4)(x+3) ; FactorialPower as a name should never appear.

Comment: You can add a layer of `RowBox[{FunctionExpand,"["...,"]"}]` around the `FactorialPower` inside `MakeExpression`.

Comment: I found it very hard to choose which answer to accept, sorry.